# How to create link to particular description element within collapsible section?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have [description items](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html) inside of [collapsible elements](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html) like below:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
        Section 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <dl>
          <dt>Element 1-1</dt>
          <dd>The description of element 1-1</dd><br>

          <dt>Element 1-2</dt>
          <dd>The description of element 1-2</dd><br>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
        Section 2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <dl>
          <dt>Element 2-1</dt>
          <dd>The description of element 2-1</dd><br>

          <dt>Element 2-2</dt>
          <dd>The description of element 2-2</dd><br>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, content of both sections is hidden by default. How can I support direct links to:

1. section 2 (so, the content of the section should be shown);
2. element 2-2 (so, the content of the section 2 should be shown and element 2-2 should be focused)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use hash url e.g. `#section2/element2`

Then hook to 2 events: `window.onload` and `window.onhashchange`
In the event handlers, process `location.hash` and programmatically expand the specific section and then focus specific element in the section.